# Python Django. Не отображаются изменения css на странице html в браузере

Tags: python, html, css, django, веб-программирование

Ошибка заключается в том, когда вносятся изменения в код css и перезагружается страница, изменения на сайте не появляются, хотя всё ранее работало, проблем с интернетом, ошибками с подключениями путей path в файле views.py не было.

Данные изменения появляются только спустя час, два и т.д. Хотя, когда вёрстка запущена на локальном пк, все изменения происходят отлично.

Каким образом данную проблему возможно решить?

Comment: Забываете чистить кэш браузера?

Comment: Возможно, надеюсь поможет

Comment: это когда публикуете в сеть?

Answer (score 1):

Это скорее всего из-за кэширование статичных файлов браузером.

Есть несколько способов решить это:

1. Подходит если сайт на стадии разработки и пользователей нет - просто чистить кэш, например, Ctrl + F5
2. Это уже если у вас есть пользователи и им в голову не придет чистить кэш). Вам следует добавлять префиксы к css/js файлам, например, style.css?v=1 и v=1 менять каждый раз при публикации в сеть